# How to get the index positions (x,y) of the keys of a variably deep Trie in Ruby

Tags: ruby, xls

I have a **Trie** structure like below:

```
{
 "Canada"=>
       {"Male"=>
            {"Children"=>{}, "Old"=>{}, "Teenager"=>{}}, 
        "Female"=>
            {"Children"=>{}, "Old"=>{}, "Teenager"=>{}}
       }, 
 "France"=>
       {"Male"=>
            {"Children"=>{}, "Old"=>{}, "Teenager"=>{}}, 
       "Female"=>
            {"Children"=>{}, "Old"=>{}, "Teenager"=>{}}}
}
```

that I built using this program:

```
class Trie < Hash
  def initialize
    super
  end

  def build(string)
    string.split("::").inject(self) do |h, key|
      h[key] ||= { }
      # puts h.inspect
    end
  end
end

trie = Trie.new
trie.build('Canada::Male::Children')
trie.build('Canada::Male::Old')
trie.build('Canada::Male::Teenager')
trie.build('Canada::Female::Children')
trie.build('Canada::Female::Old')
trie.build('Canada::Female::Teenager')
trie.build('France::Male::Children')
trie.build('France::Male::Old')
trie.build('France::Male::Teenager')
trie.build('France::Female::Children')
trie.build('France::Female::Old')
trie.build('France::Female::Teenager')
puts trie.inspect
```

I need to iterate through the trie and get the co-ordinates (x,y index) of each key as I intend to put these in an excel file like [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/s5rmp8qfin9astb/sample_data.xls).

e.g. co-ordinates (x,y) of: (assuming there is no Date column like the excel file for simplicity)

```
"Canada" = 0,0 
"Canada --> Male" = 1,0 
"Canada --> Male --> Children" = 2,0
"Canada --> Male --> Old" = 2,1
"Canada --> Male --> Teenager" = 2,2
"Canada --> Female" = 1,1 
"Canada --> Female --> Children" = 2,3
"Canada --> Female --> Old" = 2,4
"Canada --> Female --> Teenager" = 2,5
"France" = 0,6 
"France --> Male" = 1,6 
"France --> Male --> Children" = 2,6
```

**EDIT_1:**

I want to build an excel file like [this.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/s5rmp8qfin9astb/sample_data.xls) from the Trie that I built in my program.

Please look at the position of the keys from the trie in the excel file and look at the merging of cells. Pretty self explanatory.

**EDIT_2**

Here is an iterative solution that I wrote which works for depth 2 only.

```
# coding: utf-8
require 'open-uri'
require 'spreadsheet'

dataset = [['Date', 'Canada::Male', 'Canada::Female', 'Canada::Total', 'France::Male', 'France::Female', 'France::Total'], ['2014-05-20', '10', '20', '30', '10', '20', '30'], ['2014-05-19', '20', '20', '40', '10', '20', '30'], ['2014-05-18', '20', '20', '40', '10', '25', '35']]

column_names = dataset[0]
column_hash = Hash.new{|h,k| h[k] = []}

column_names.each do |c|
  if c.include? "::"
    key_val = c.split("::")
    key = key_val[0]
    val = key_val[1]
    column_hash[key] << val
  end
end

dummy_row = Array.new(column_names.size)

book = Spreadsheet::Workbook.new
sheet = book.create_worksheet
sheet.row(0).replace(dummy_row)
sheet.row(1).replace(dummy_row)

dataset.each_with_index do |row, i|
  next if i == 0
  sheet.row(i+1).replace(row)
end

sheet.rows[0][0] = dataset[0][0]

# col_hash_key_size =  column_hash.keys.size

column_hash.keys.each_with_index do |key,i|
  size = column_hash[key].size
  sheet.rows[0][(i*size)+1] = key
end

# sheet.merge_cells(start_row, start_col, end_row, end_col)
column_hash.keys.each_with_index do |key,i|
  size = column_hash[key].size
  sheet.merge_cells(0, (i*size)+1, 0, (i+1)*size)
end

column_hash.keys.each_with_index do |key,i|
  size = column_hash[key].size
  column_hash[key].each_with_index do |val,ind|
    sheet.rows[1][(i*size)+ind+1] = val
  end
end

book.write "test.xls"
```

I want to build a generalized algorithm which will work for variable depth i.e. not only for `Canada::Male` but also for `Canada::Male::Children`.

Comment: What have you tried? It seems that a little bit of `each_with_index` would do the trick.

Comment: Keen, I suggest you clarify the form of the output you desired. I assumed in my answer, for example, that it is a hash.

Comment: Keen, I now see you are as interested in writing the hash to a spreadsheet as constructing the hash in the first place. I'm afraid I can't help you with the latter. In hindsight, it may have been been better to confine the question to the construction of the hash, then ask a separate question on how to write that information to a spreadsheet. I expect the downvotes are mainly related to your statement, "...I want to create an excel sheet (using spreadsheet gem) from this trie structured hash.", as what you are referencing is not a hash.  I suggest you edit to make it a hash.

Comment: Thanks for the compliment, Keen, but the truth is that my knowledge of Ruby is quite narrow, I have no experience using it for real applications and don't know anything about writing data to a spreadsheet. There are others here that could help you with the latter, however, so I suggest that you post a new question that is focused on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple recursive function that outputs the position of each key in the spreadsheet.

```
def to_coords hash, x = 0, y = 0
  hash.each do |k, v|
    puts "#{x},#{y} #{k}"
    x = to_coords(v, x, y + 1)
  end
  return x + (hash.empty? ? 1 : 0)
end
```

For your example, this outputs

```
0,0 Canada
0,1 Male
0,2 Children
1,2 Old
2,2 Teenager
3,1 Female
3,2 Children
4,2 Old
5,2 Teenager
6,0 France
6,1 Male
6,2 Children
7,2 Old
8,2 Teenager
9,1 Female
9,2 Children
10,2 Old
11,2 Teenager
```

You didn't give a full example of your input so this will need to be tweaked a bit to fit your application. The basic idea is that if you are at the bottom level (Children, Old, Teenager), then each key is just shifted over by one, hence the `hash.empty? ? 1 : 0`. If you are not at the bottom level then iterating over the subhashes tells you what X value to use next.

Comment: Done. Though you've gone from too little info to too much. The trie stuff seems irrelevant as your question would apply to any nested Hash. Your example input and the example spreadsheet are useful. It is not clear what you're asking for: an algorithm to find cell positions or full code to produce the spreadsheet with merged cells and the like?

Comment: @KeenLearner Then your question is too broad. If you already have a working iterative version, why can't you just replace your iterative code with my recursive code? I wrote this code for you because it was a somewhat interesting algorithmic problem. I have no interest in doing all of the work for you.

Comment: Please carefully compare your example output to my algorithm's output. If you cannot figure out the difference between them on your own, you have a bigger problem on your hands.

Comment: SO is not a "get people to do work for you for free" site. If you couldn't even put in the effort to see what my algorithm was doing before telling me to "correct" it, I have no interest in answering your question.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of a couple of ways of doing this, but both obviously require recursion.

**Method #1**

```
def depth_and_position(h, g={}, keys = [], depth=0)
  h.each_key.with_index do |k,i|
    g[(keys + [k]).join(' < ')] = [depth,i]
    depth_and_position(h[k], g, keys + [k], depth + 1) unless h[k].empty?
  end
  g
end
```

*Example*

```
h = {"Canada"=>
       {"Male"=>   {"Children"=>{}, "Old"=>{}, "Teenager"=>{}}, 
        "Female"=> {"Children"=>{}, "Old"=>{}, "Teenager"=>{}}}, 
     "France"=>
       {"Male"=>   {"Children"=>{}, "Old"=>{}, "Teenager"=>{}}, 
       "Female"=>  {"Children"=>{}, "Old"=>{}, "Teenager"=>{}}}}

b = depth_and_position(h)
  #=> {"Canada"=>[0, 0],
  #    "Canada < Male"=>[1, 0],
  #    "Canada < Male < Children"=>[2, 0],
  #    "Canada < Male < Old"=>[2, 1],
  #    "Canada < Male < Teenager"=>[2, 2],
  #    "Canada < Female"=>[1, 1],
  #    "Canada < Female < Children"=>[2, 0],
  #    "Canada < Female < Old"=>[2, 1],
  #    "Canada < Female < Teenager"=>[2, 2],
  #    "France"=>[0, 1],
  #    "France < Male"=>[1, 0],
  #    "France < Male < Children"=>[2, 0],
  #    "France < Male < Old"=>[2, 1],
  #    "France < Male < Teenager"=>[2, 2],
  #    "France < Female"=>[1, 1],
  #    "France < Female < Children"=>[2, 0],
  #    "France < Female < Old"=>[2, 1],
  #    "France < Female < Teenager"=>[2, 2]}
```

**Method #2**

If we had the array:

```
keys(h)
  #=> [["Canada"],
  #    ["Canada", "Male"],
  #    ["Canada", "Male", "Children"],
  #    ["Canada", "Male", "Old"],
  #    ["Canada", "Male", "Teenager"],
  #    ["Canada", "Female"],
  #    ["Canada", "Female", "Children"],
  #    ["Canada", "Female", "Old"],
  #    ["Canada", "Female", "Teenager"],
  #    ["France"],
  #    ["France", "Male"],
  #    ["France", "Male", "Children"],
  #    ["France", "Male", "Old"],
  #    ["France", "Male", "Teenager"],
  #    ["France", "Female"],
  #    ["France", "Female", "Children"],
  #    ["France", "Female", "Old"],
  #    ["France", "Female", "Teenager"]]
```

computing the above hash would be straightforward, for the `depth` associated with each subarray `a` (e.g., `["Canada", "Male", "Old"`) would be `a.size-1` and the second parameter could be easily obtained by counting.

The above array could be computed as follows:

```
def keys(h, a=[], keys = [])
  h.each_key do |k|
    a << (keys + [k])
    keys(h[k], a, keys + [k]) unless h[k].empty?
  end
  a
end
```

The hash could then be constructed from this array thusly:

```
def depth_and_position(h)
  keys(h).chunk(&:size).each_with_object({}) { |(nbr,a),g|
    a.each_with_index { |k,i| g[k.join(' > ')] = [nbr-1, i] } }
end
```

*Explanation*

After computing `keys(h)` we obtain the enumerator:

```
enum1 = keys(h).chunk(&:size)
  #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator::Generator:0x00000101a01340>:each>
```

We can convert this to array to see what elements the enumerator will pass to its block:

```
enum1.to_a
  #=> [[1, [["Canada"]]],
  #    [2, [["Canada", "Male"]]],
  #    [3, [["Canada", "Male", "Children"],
  #         ["Canada", "Male", "Old"],
  #         ["Canada", "Male", "Teenager"]]],
  #    [2, [["Canada", "Female"]]],
  #    [3, [["Canada", "Female", "Children"],
  #         ["Canada", "Female", "Old"],
  #         ["Canada", "Female", "Teenager"]]],
  #    [1, [["France"]]],
  #    ...
  #         ["France", "Female", "Teenager"]]]]
```

By passing [Enumerable#each_with_object](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_index) to this enumerator, with the object being an empty hash (represented by the block variable `g`) we obtain another enumerator:

```
enum2 = enum1.each_with_object({})
  #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator:
        #<Enumerator::Generator:0x00000101a01340>:each>:each_with_object({})>
```

Note

```
enum2.to_a
  #=> [[[1, [["Canada"]]], {}],
  #    [[2, [["Canada", "Male"]]], {}],
  #    [[3, [["Canada", "Male", "Children"],
  #          ["Canada", "Male", "Old"],
  #          ["Canada", "Male", "Teenager"]]], {}],
  #   ...
  #    [[3, [["France", "Female", "Children"],
  #          ["France", "Female", "Old"],
  #          ["France", "Female", "Teenager"]]], {}]]
```

The hash is initially empty, but will of course be non-empty after the first element is passed to the block.

The rest is relatively straightforward.